# Projectile motion

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure, projectile

I am supposed to write a script that provides multiple lines of projectile motion but my code doesn't seem to give me what I need.

```
disp('This program will calculate the trajectory of a ball thrown at an initial speed vo \n')
v0 = input('Please enter the initial speed');
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;
g = 9.81;%m/s^2
T = 5 : 5 : 85;
vx = v0*cosd(T);
vy = v0*sind(T);
t = (2*v0.*sind(T))/g;
y = y0 + (vy.*t) - ((g.*(t.^2))/2);
x = x0 + vx.*t;
plot(x,y)
```

This is how the graph should look like:

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `T` represents the initial degree. You want to calculate `x` and `y` for different initial degrees (`5:5:85`). Use a for loop for `T` and plot `x` and `y` for different `t`.

```
disp('This program will calculate the trajectory of a ball thrown at an initial speed vo \n')
v0 = input('Please enter the initial speed');
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;
g = 9.81;%m/s^2
for T = 5 : 5 : 85
    vx = v0*cosd(T);
    vy = v0*sind(T);
    t = linspace(0,(2*v0.*sind(T))/g,100);
    y = y0 + (vy.*t) - ((g.*(t.^2))/2);
    x = x0 + vx.*t;
    plot(x,y)
    hold on
    xlim([-inf inf])
    ylim([-inf inf])
end
```

Output:

```
This program will calculate the trajectory of a ball thrown at an initial speed vo \n
Please enter the initial speed10
```

[image]